# android jellybean prebuilt binaires on panda board not booting up

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, pandaboard

I am trying to bring up panda-board omap4430 with Android jellybean pre-built binaries, which I have downloaded from linaro.org (http://releases.linaro.org/12.12/android/panda/).
I am creating two partitions on SD card into file systems.
First is bootable FAT32 containing boot.tar.bz2 and u-boot.img and other ext3 partition is having   userdata.tar.bz2 and    system.tar.bz2.
After putting my SD card in panda board & connecting it through minicom on my Ubuntu pc, I am not able to see even a single charecter of untaring or something or any logs.
Am I missing something.
I have done Ubuntu porting on Beagle board earlier successfully.

Answer (score 1):

you are flashing it first time on panda board then it has some other method, as they have given like below process

format sd card

copy MLO and u-boot.bin in fat 32 partitions

then follow the given process on OMAPpedia release nots.